# Can you run selenium scripts on a locked computer and come back to check on it in 2 hrs?

Tags: selenium

Can you run selenium on a locked computer?
I noticed some of my tests fail intermittently on a locked computer. I also tried to increase wait time between clicks and find elements to see if it helps. Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. On linux, you can run commadline utility [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen). It allows you to have 10 separate terminal sessions. You can detach them and attach later, even from home or another computer.

You can even name those sessions so you can see into which window you want to switch. Very handy, I have 2 screen sessions running all the time. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if Windows or Mac will allow you to run selenium scripts on a locked computer?

Comment: Mac in Unix so screen utility should be available. Windows is NOT unix so I do not think such convenient commandline utilities are available.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue by downloading a program that makes the mouse keep moving so the computer won't lock. Then the tests passed.